# How to provide JSON Object ID in gorest EndPoint syntax for output data?

Tags: json, go, mustache

I'm new to Go and GoRest, but I have question regarding it.

How to provide JSON Object ID in gorest EndPoint syntax for output data described below?

I have simple example:

```
type HelloService struct {
    gorest.RestService `root:"/api" consumes:"application/json" produces:"application/json"`
    playList    gorest.EndPoint `method:"GET" path:"/list/" output:"[]Item"`
    playItem    gorest.EndPoint `method:"PUT" path:"/go/{Id:int}" postdata:"Item"`
}


func(serv HelloService) PlayList() []Item{
    serv.ResponseBuilder().SetResponseCode(200)
    return itemStore

}


type Item struct{
    Id              int
    FileName        string
    Active          bool
}

var(
    itemStore []Item
)
```

And the resulting JSON Is:

```
[{"Id":1,"FileName":"test :1","Active":false},{"Id":2,"FileName":"test :2","Active":false}, ... ]
```

But,Mustache.js can't parse it because it needs object ID first.
Mustache wants something like this:

```
{
 "repo": [{"Id":1,"FileName":"test :1","Active":false},{"Id":2,"FileName":"test      
:2","Active":false}, ... ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to change

`playList    gorest.EndPoint`method:"GET" path:"/list/" output:"[]Item"`

to 
`playList    gorest.EndPoint`method:"GET" path:"/list/" output:"ItemStore"`

and

```
var(
    itemStore []Item
)
```

to

```
type ItemStore struct {
    Items []Item
}

var(
    itemStore ItemStore
)
```

A complete working program would be much easier to debug.

Comment: {"Items":[{"Id":1,"FileName":"test :1","Active":false}, {"Id":2,"FileName":"test :2","Active":false},{"Id":3,"FileName":"test :3","Active":false},{"Id":4,"FileName":"test :4","Active":false},{"Id":5,"FileName":"test :5","Active":false},{"Id":6,"FileName":"test :6","Active":false},{"Id":7,"FileName":"test :7","Active":false},{"Id":8,"FileName":"test :8","Active":false},{"Id":9,"FileName":"test :9","Active":false},{"Id":10,"FileName":"test :10","Active":false}]}

Comment: only one remark, here is misspelling in this string:  playList gorest.EndPointmethod:"GET" path:"/list/" output:"itemStore"`   ... correct one  playList gorest.EndPointmethod:"GET" path:"/list/" output:"ItemStore"`